# How to reactivate NVM?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I misunderstood the meaning of `nvm deactivate` and thought it was to switch between nvm and brew version of node, and used the command. Is there a method to reactivate NVM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NVM deactivate only affect on current shell. You can open a new shell and regain the effect. It removed any NVM path from the current shell.

Comment: Also, is there a method to use switch to brew version of node when using nvm?

Comment: @AeroWang: That's a separate question, and should be asked as one. This is not *answer my list of questions in comments*. This answers the question you've asked here.

Comment: @AeroWang To switch to brew version, use `nvm deactivate` (temporary on current shell). Or if you want it to persist on every new shell `nvm alias default system`

Comment: `nvm deactivate` seems to make `node` command not found, let me try `nvm alias default system`

Comment: @AeroWang That is because you don't have node binary in your path, have you installed via homebrew?

Comment: `nvm alias default system` works. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625898/is-there-a-method-to-use-switch-to-brew-version-of-node-when-using-nvm