# Is there a method to use switch to Homebrew version of node when using nvm?

Tags: node.js, homebrew, nvm

Lots of my packages such as heroku depends on Homebrew’s node, so I have to keep one in the system. I wonder if I can switch between nvm and Homebrew’s node so I don't have to upgrade twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For temporary switch, use `nvm use system`

For every new shell Use `nvm alias default system` to use brew version.